# ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'my:project': sonar.sources

Tags: sonarqube

When I run `sonar-scanner` in my project directory, it throws an error like 
"
**ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution 

ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'my:project': sonar.sources**
"

[image]

Comment: could you please share your sonar-project.properties file?

Comment: Here is my sonar-project.properties file-- 
sonar.projectKey=my:project
sonar.projectName=My project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.exclusions=**/node_nodules/**, **/dist/**